# How to draw camera screen oval draw oval as in the picture

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to draw camera screen with oval shape and border as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try this below code :

```
   Align(
        child: Container(
          height: 160,
          width: 90,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.elliptical(
                90,
                170,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text('     '),
        ),
      ),
```

And your output look like this -> [image: Output Screen]

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about this icon?

```
Icon(Icons.camera)
```

[image]